# How can I read the number below [i, j] in a multidimensional array?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game in unity 3D that begins by creating a world map. I assign each tile a height value to determine the landscape, but when I try to read the height values of the surrounding tiles, the program freezes.

This is my first time using Multidimensional arrays, so I am likely doing something wrong. otherwise, I have tried rearranging the logic and thinking through it but I haven't found anything.

I start by filling the multidimensional array with random heights, like so:

```
public int worldWidth; 
public int worldHeight;
int[,] tileHeight = new int[4, 4];

//assign height values
    for (int j = 0; j < worldWidth; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < worldHeight; i++)
            {
                tileHeight[j, i] = Random.Range(15, 115);
            }

        }
```

After that, I Instantiate the tiles, but I believe that code is irrelevant.
Next, I take each tile, read the height above, under, left, and right of it, and average the total. Then I save that number to the multidimensional array in its appropriate location. Here is my code:

```
            {
                for (int p = 0; p < worldWidth; p++)
                {
                    int NHeight;
                    int EHeight;
                    int SHeight;
                    int WHeight;

                    //if (o > 0) { NHeight = tileHeight[o--, p]; } else { NHeight = 0; }

                    //if (p != 3) { EHeight = tileHeight[o, p++]; } else { EHeight = 0; }
                    //if (o != 3) { SHeight = tileHeight[o++, p]; } else { SHeight = 0; }
                    //if (p != 0) { WHeight = tileHeight[o, p--]; } else { WHeight = 0; }

                    plane[o, p] = (NHeight + EHeight + SHeight + WHeight) / 4;
                }
            }
```

To clarify what I'm trying to do here, let me give an example. Let's say I have the multidimensional array:

```
{ {3, 5, 2},
  {2, 8, 5},
  {4, 6, 2} }
```

my code would ideally start at [0, 0], or 4, and get the numbers 2, 6, 0, and 0 and average them together, getting 2. then my array would look like:

```
{ {3, 5, 2},
  {2, 8, 5},
  {2, 6, 2} }
```

after that, my code should go to [0, 1], or 6, and get the numbers 2, 8, 2, and 0, for an answer of 3, making my array look like:

```
{ {3, 5, 2},
  {2, 8, 5},
  {2, 3, 2} }
```

I'd like for this to go through the whole array.

I have a few issues. When I don't run the four commented lines of code and run `Debug.Log();` everything works. When I start to run the code with the commented lines, however, it starts to skip rows of the array and if I run all four the program freezes (or takes so long that I assume it has frozen). I assume that there is a flaw in my logic, but I have stared at this code on and off for the last 4 hours and I can't find anything. I also feel like there may be something wrong with the way I'm reading from `tileHeight` in the for loops. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `p++` is not the same as `p+1`. It has the effect of incrementing `p`, which explains why rows are getting skipped.

Comment: Okay! That explains a lot and makes sense. Thanks!